# Trouble understanding Bentley-Ottmann algorithm

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I am working on implementing the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm, but I've come across a case where I'm struggling to understand how the algorithm is supposed to find a particular intersection.

I've sketched out the problem below. The black lines indicate the line segments, the green line shows the "sweep line", and the red lines indicate which y-coordinate is being used in the active segment ordering. The plot is repeated for 5 steps of the sweep line proceedure. However, following the algorithm from Wikipedia, the intersection BC can't be found.

The algorithm is stated on Wikipedia as follows:
[image]

In particular, when I come to the LeftEndpoint(C) event in Step 3, the y-coordinate of C is **below** the y-coordinate of A(left). According to the algorithm, for left-endpoint events, I need to find the above and below segments, check if they intersect and remove that intersection. Then, I need to check if this new segment intersects with either of the above/below segments. Here, A is the upper segment of C, therefore, I only need to check if A intersects C, which it doesn't. So no intersection event gets created.

In the next step, we come to the RightEndpoint(C) event. Here, according to the algorithm, we only need ot check if the above/below segments intersect. Here, these are B and A, which don't intersect, so we report no intersection. After this point, we've completely removed the segment C, without reporting its intersection with B. This is clearly incorrect.

[image]

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You seem to be interpreting "above/below segments" as referring solely to the leftmost points of each segment.  I'm pretty sure it's supposed to mean the intersections with the current sweep line - in your middle step, A is *below* C, and B is above.

Comment: This certainly would solve the issue and was my thought as well, but this doesn't seem to be stated anywhere in the algorithm pseudocode. Recomputing the intersection points on the segments would certainly add additional computational overhead, so I would like to make sure that this is, in fact, what the algorithm suggests, and that I haven't missed something in the instructions.

Comment: Think of it this way - what would be the point of having a "sweep line" in the algorithm (rather than a "current point" or similar) if you were never going to treat it as a line?  Computational overhead should be small, just calculate the slope of each segment *once*, and you can easily calculate the intersections.

Comment: I implemented this algorithm many years ago.  @jasonharper is correct. You should  strongly consider getting the original paper. Wikipedia pseudocode tends to have subtle errors. Note that if you try to use floating point arithmetic, degenerate cases like lines that are very nearly parallel and multiple intersections very close together can easily make it unstable. Rational arithmetic is helpful. Vertical lines are also fiddly.